# validation and model binding in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am making an application which has student class.

it is as follows. this is sample pseudo description. (don`t bother about syntax)

```
    public class student{

             [required]
             string name;

             int id;
             List<course> courses;

       }

      public class course{

       [required]
       string name;

       }
```

student class has list of courses. now when i bind this as model to view. view has a text field for name and the grid for courses which has course name. if i submit the form  with out entering the name of student.the validation fires automatically. but for the courses it is not firing up. though on the controller side model state is considered invalid. but client side validation is not firing up.

again i am posting sort of pesudocode can`t post actual code.

```
          @using (Html.BeginForm("create", "student", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createStudent" }))
          {
             @Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.name)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)
             <table><tr>

                  <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("courses[0].name")<br/>
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("course[0].name")
                  </td>

             </table>
             <input type="submit"></input>
          }
```

now clicking on submit for doesnot fire validation for course name . but model.state is invalid. 
if i enter something in course name the model is validated.

but i want to display validation on the page as it is firing for student name.

Please suggest me something

note:- i also tried (for course name) this.

```
        @Html.TextBox("courses[0].Name", "", new { @class = "input-xlarge", id = "txtPropName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.courses[0].Name)
```

Comment: Apart from all the syntax errors, this works fine (just copied it to my project and the client side validation errors show for both properties if they are empty). There must be other issues with you code.

Comment: yes i tried this in new project and it is working. but in this current project i am not able to get it to running state. what i have done so far. 1) our designing team has done some changes in bootstrap.js. 2) i have made few chages in Routes.config and Bundleconfig.cs. since validation is firing for simple properties so  i assume all my js files are included in _layout.cshtml

Comment: Since validation is working server side but not client side, chances are it something to with javascipt.

Comment: thank you very much. i will dig deep in to it. my best regards